# Importing videos from folder to HTML

Tags: html

Hey can someone help me how to put a video path in HTML. I want to import a video from my folder and put it in my code. Does anyone know how?

Comment: You can reference this article. [Go to tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) tag to insert playable video's in your code if that is what you mean